# What's the Markdown Editor that Stack Overflow is using?

Tags: support, editor

Is it custom? If not, what editor is it and where we can find it?

Comment: The 'official' Pagedown repo we had for it is now adorned with a big fat "Google code is shutting down" thing, I think this is a fair question. Checking now to see if we've migrated it anywhere else.

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121981/stackoverflow-official-wmd-editor

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It's called [Pagedown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/), and you're totally free to use it :) It's a great editor for markdown with restricted HTML support.

Google code is shutting down so the repo is read-only, however we have plans to migrate it the next time that we have something to commit. [Balpha](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha) maintains it; when it moves, we'll make sure that folks know about it.

Comment: Is it a coincidence that the Pagedown page is going down? I guess creating this project initiated the Google Code shutdown...

Comment: Can you guys maintain a forked repo on github? (_since it is opensource_)

Comment: https://github.com/maniator/pagedown/ @Mr_Green (i clicked on export to github)

Comment: @Neal I actually did `npm install pagedown` but thought balpha(_author_) might maintain on github. Anyway, I did star your repo. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green ha sorry :-( True.